# Common mode choke to boost cmrr of transformer input

Tags: amplifier, choke, cmrr

I was wondering, can a common mode choke be used to enhance the CMRR of a transformer coupled amplifier Even further?

What are the drawbacks?

Comment: in theory, yes, but actually, it depends. What CMRR does your amplifier system already have?

Comment: I'm not really building something. I was just wondering if it is used somewhere. I know they can be used to boost cmrr of instrumentation amplifiers and transformers help with cmrr as well. So I thought is it possible to combine these techniques.

Comment: probably is – but deciding whether or not to do so depends on a lot of things. For example, if your amplifier is a digital one, why not do the suppression in DSP? Would be cheaper. If your signal is an RF one, then the CMRR of the common mode choke might be far less than the effects you don't want to introduce. If your signal is already powerful, a common mode choke might get hot etc

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Study the magnetics used in Ethernet, for example. Also what a balun actually does.

Comment: transformers used in laptop chargers are horrible couplers of CM noise due to imbalanced coupling and load impedance.. If you have ever tried an external stick mic you would know.   The usual solution is ground the floating unit via external video port or other method and using a larger CM balun around DC cable.